# Ломается верстка

Tags: html, css, frontend

Есть сайт с таким кодом:

```
div#container
{
   width: 1349px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
   text-align: left;
}
body
{
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   color: #000000;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 13px;
   line-height: 1.1875;max-width: 1349px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; }

  <div style="width: 1349px;
position: fixed;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 127px;
text-align: left;
z-index: 10000;
border-bottom: 7px;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
background-color: #FFF;">

        <div style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:-6px;width:415px;height:131px;z-index:75;">
        <img src="images/logo.png" tppabs="http://xn--b1adem0afhe.xn--90ais/images/logo.png" id="indexImage7" alt=""></div>

     <div  style="position:absolute;left:420px;top:12px;width:700px;height:51px;z-index:64;text-align:left;">
   <span style="color:#30BF00;font-family:Arial;font-size:22px;"><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#akciya"><b style="color:#30BF00;">ДВЕРИ В РАССРОЧКУ. Доступно и удобно</b></a></span></div>

        <div style="position:absolute;left:910px;top:10px;width:30px;height:30px;z-index:76;">
        <img src="images/vel.png" tppabs="http://xn--b1adem0afhe.xn--90ais/images/vel.png" id="indexImage8" alt=""></div>
        <div id="wb_indexImage8" style="position:absolute;left:915px;top:49px;width:24px;height:24px;z-index:76;">
        <img src="images/mts.png" tppabs="http://xn--b1adem0afhe.xn--90ais/images/mts.png" id="indexImage8" alt=""></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;left:915px;top:85px;width:24px;height:24px;z-index:76;">
        <img src="images/call.png" tppabs="http://xn--b1adem0afhe.xn--90ais/images/call.png" id="indexImage8" alt=""></div>

     <div style="position:absolute;left:879px;top:10px;width:322px;height:37px;text-align:right;z-index:66;">
        <span style="color:#474444;font-family:Arial;font-size:28px;"><strong>+375 (29) 680  10 13</strong></span></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;left:879px;top:45px;width:322px;height:37px;text-align:right;z-index:66;">
        <span style="color:#474444;font-family:Arial;font-size:28px;"><strong>+375 (33) 900  10 13</strong></span></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;left:879px;top:80px;width:322px;height:37px;text-align:right;z-index:66;">
        <span style="color:#474444;font-family:Arial;font-size:28px;"><strong>+375 (17) 282 73 80</strong></span></div>
     <div style="position:absolute;left:470px;top:30px;width:369px;height:83px;z-index:67;">

     <a class="preorder-bigestbtn popup_button" href="#" rel="preorder_window"  target="_self" onmouseover="SetImage('indexImage10','images/zvonokdark.png'/*tpa=http://xn--b1adem0afhe.xn--90ais/images/zvonokdark.png*/);return false;" onmouseout="SetImage('indexImage10','images/zvonok.png'/*tpa=http://xn--b1adem0afhe.xn--90ais/images/zvonok.png*/);return false;"><img src="images/zvonok.png" tppabs="http://xn--b1adem0afhe.xn--90ais/images/zvonok.png" id="indexImage10" alt=""></a></div>
</div>
```

Все блоки на месте. Если делать экран шире (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>), то так же всё на месте, но если делать уже (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> , например, до 125%) то Шапка сайта съезжет. Шапка, становиться не видимой с правого края.

Как выровнять?

Comment: это зум браузера, верстка тут не причем.

Comment: На телефонах так же поломано всё

Comment: если у вас верстка фиксированная, тогда необходимо в head добавить <meta name="viewport" content='width=1360' />

Comment: Повторю комментарий здесь: ссылки недостаточно, нужен код прямо в вопросе. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Выход нашёл - нужно было задать ширину `body`. Задал `width: 1349px;` и проблема решилась.